# Nuget doesn't install dependencies when 'targetFramework' attribute isn't specified

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

According to the [nuspec reference](https://docs.nuget.org/create/nuspec-reference) chapter "Specifying Dependencies in version 2.0 and above", it's possible to declare a `dependency` in a `group` element without an additional `targetFramework` attribute, which implies that this dependency is valid for all frameworks. So I went ahead an specified the following in a .nuspec for one of my packages:

```
<dependencies>
  <group>
    <dependency id="DEPENDENCY" version="1.0.0" />
  </group>

  <group targetFramework="net40-client">
  </group>

  <group targetFramework="net45">
  </group>
</dependencies>
```

After installing the package in one of my projects, the dependency isn't there at all. Neither in the project references nor in the `packages` folder in the root of my project. However when doing this:

```
<dependencies>
  <group targetFramework="net40-client">
    <dependency id="DEPENDENCY" version="1.0.0" />
  </group>

  <group targetFramework="net45">
    <dependency id="DEPENDENCY" version="1.0.0" />
  </group>
</dependencies>
```

... it works flawlessly.

Is this a bug? ~~Do I possibly override the 'global' dependency configuration with the empty local declarations?~~ Or did I misunderstood something here?

---

**EDIT**

It's possible to declare empty dependency elements and still have 'a global one': https://github.com/dsplaisted/PCLStorage/blob/master/common/PCLStorage.nuspec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Nuget release documentation](https://docs.nuget.org/Release-Notes/NuGet-2.0):

> **There is no inheritance between groups.** If a project's target
>   framework matches the targetFramework attribute of a group, only the
>   dependencies within that group will be installed.

It means that if the project uses `net45`, `net40-client` or later - no dependencies will be installed.

The `group` element without the `targetFramework` attribute is used to install the dependencies for an early version of these frameworks (for example, `net20`).

A good example from the [Nuget release documentation](https://docs.nuget.org/Release-Notes/NuGet-2.0):

```
<dependencies> 
   <group>
      <dependency id="RouteMagic" version="1.1.0" />
   </group>

   <group targetFramework="net40">
      <dependency id="jQuery" />
      <dependency id="WebActivator" />
   </group>

   <group targetFramework="sl30">
   </group>
</dependencies>
```

> Note that a group can contain zero dependencies. In the example above,
>   if the package is installed into a project that targets Silverlight
>   3.0 or later, no dependencies will be installed. If the package is installed into a project that targets .NET 4.0 or later, two
>   dependencies, jQuery and WebActivator, will be installed. If the
>   package is installed into a project that targets an early version of
>   these 2 frameworks, or any other framework, RouteMagic 1.1.0 will be
>   installed.

Comment: forget reading, these developers need to learn the principle of least astonishment. If no target framework is specified the least astonishing thing to do would be apply the dependencies to all frameworks, not "an early version of these frameworks (for example, net20)." Who cares about net20?  Inheritance would also lead to the least amount of duplication of dependencies when targeting multiple frameworks.